# android firebase update list message

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a chat app with list of people who talked to you, like any chat app. I need to update the list, by who is the last one talk to you or who is the last one you talked to. So when I sent message to someone, I delete my line from his list and create it again and make the same on my list. This is my code:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query applesQuery = ref.child(theUID).child("messages").orderByChild("lastUIDTalkedTo").equalTo(hisU);

applesQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


        if (dataSnapshot.exists())
        {
            for (DataSnapshot appleSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                appleSnapshot.getRef().removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                        FirebaseDatabase hisDbMessageList = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                        final DatabaseReference hisDocMessageList = hisDbMessageList.getReference(hisUID).child("messages").push();
                        hisDocMessageList.setValue(new MessagesListModel(theUID , id , nickName , handle , country , returnThePostDate() ,
                                returnPostTime() , theUID , false));
                    }
                });
            }
        }else
        {
            FirebaseDatabase hisDbMessageList = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            final DatabaseReference hisDocMessageList = hisDbMessageList.getReference(hisUID).child("messages").push();
            hisDocMessageList.setValue(new MessagesListModel(theUID , id , nickName , handle , country , returnThePostDate() ,
                    returnPostTime() , theUID , false));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

It is not working good all the time. Any idea to make it works really good?

Comment: "It is not working good all the time" what does this mean?

Comment: If you would be a bit more precise with the problem you're facing, maybe we can help.

Comment: @ZUNJAE it sometimes did not delete the child and the list full of the same person who messaged